# SAM: Import local module into lamda function

Tags: python, sam

I have several AWS lambda functions in a single repo. The functions share some common code that I  have pulled out into a module. My project structure is like this

```
template.yaml
lambda1
--app.py
--requirements.txt
lambda2
--app2.py
--requirements.txt
commoncode
--__init__.py
--commonutils1.py
--commonutils2.py
```

I can run the code locally, but when I do a sam build it builds the lambda1 and lambda2 functions but it does not pull in the commoncode module.

Do I need to add something to my requirements.txt to pull in my local modules?